# Creating Grid with Numpy Performance

Tags: python, numpy, grid

So here is what I try to do,

```
N=1000
x=np.arange(0,1,1./float(len(N)))    
XX,YY=np.meshgrid(x,x)   

l=len(XX)
grid=np.array([ ([XX[i,i],YY[j,j],0. ]) for i in xrange(l) for j in xrange(l) ])
```

the numpy routine is rather fast but I need the grid to be in a different form and this takes quite long (I guess because of indexing the numpy array).

Thanks for any suggestions : )

Cheers

Comment: len(N) doesn't work by the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take advantage of [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
z = np.zeros([N, N, 3])
z[:,:,0] = x.reshape(-1,1)
z[:,:,1] = x
fast_grid = z.reshape(N*N, 3)

print np.all( grid == fast_grid ) 
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
grid = np.mgrid[:N, :N, :1]
grid = grid.T.reshape(-1, 3)
```